# performing calculation in each line of datafile

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Python and I just want to perform a simple calculation on all data in a file. I have the median number from another file and for each line in dataFast I want to do this:
medianNum - eachline + medianNum

This is what i have so far

```
medianNum=np.median(myList)

array = open('dataFast.csv','rb')
outfile = [medianNum - x + medianNum for x in array]
```

dataFast.csv is in one row with a value in each cell and looks like this: [0.123] [0,111] [0.222] etc

Comment: What's your question / what specifically do you need help with

Comment: `medianNum - eachline + medianNum`? Is that `2 * medianNum - eachline`? Why don't you write it this way?

Comment: the output file is blank

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('dataFast.csv', 'r') as f:
    arr = f.read().replace('][', ' ').replace(']', '').replace('[', '').replace('\n', ' ').replace(',', '.').replace('  ', ' ').split()
    with open('outputfile', 'w') as fout:
        fout.write('\n'.join([str(2 * medianNum - float(value)) for value in arr]))
```

Comment: There was a misprint. Fixed it.

Comment: Thank you. But i'm still coming up against the same problem - the outputfile.csv is blank...

Comment: @user2466084 It is `outputfile` without extension in my code. And it's not blank for me. Could you add contents for some `dataFast.csv` into your question?

Comment: dataFast.csv is in one row with a value in each cell and looks like this: [0.123] [0,111] [0.222] etc

Comment: @user2466084 That's not file with a number on each line, as I thought. Fixed the answer.

Comment: ahh ok. I see. Its still black but i suspect this is because medianNum is in the same [0.111] format. is there a way to convert this too?

Comment: @user2466084 Read manual about working with strings in python. Remove brackets and cast it to float.

Comment: ok thanks. could you repaste your original answer where the calculation is based on a list rather than array

Comment: @user2466084 See revision 1 of my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16998676/1